# how to get connected clients in flask

Tags: python, sockets, flask

hi i need to display total number of connected clients on my flask app i write this code for checking connected and disconnected connections.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
clients = []

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/')
def connect():
    clients.append(request.namespace)

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/')
def disconnect():
    clients.remove(request.namespace)
```

then i render template like this

`return render_template_string(TABLE_TEMPLATE, data=data, clients=len(clients))`

In html part i call like this

`<h1>{{ clients }} </h1>`

but on webpage it keep showing `0` even client is connect i get output from client and it is connected it should print `1` `2` depends how many clients are connected. even if i print this print(len(clients)) it return `0`. even my client is connect and i get output.

[image]

this is my updated code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, logge=True)
clients = 0

@socketio.on("connect", namespace="/")
def connect():
    # global variable as it needs to be shared
    global clients
    clients += 1
    # emits a message with the user count anytime someone connects
    emit("users", {"user_count": clients}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on("disconnect", namespace="/")
def disconnect():
    global clients
    clients -= 1
    emit("users", {"user_count": clients}, broadcast=True)


TABLE_TEMPLATE = """
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var namespace = '/';    
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
        // Update the counter when a new user connects
        socket.on('users', function(users) {
            userCount = document.getElementById('user_counter');
            userCount.innerHTML = users.user_count;
        });
});
</script>
<h1 id='user_counter'></h1>
<style>
   table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
</style>
<table style="width: 100%">
   <thead>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>IP</th>
      <th>Status</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for row in data %}
      <tr>
         <td><center>{{ row.client }}</td></center>
         <td><center>{{ row.ip }}</td></center>
         <td><center>{{ row.status }}</td></center>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
"""


@app.route("/device_add", methods=['POST'])
def device_add():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    with open('logs.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{name} Connected USB from IP: {request.remote_addr} \n')
    return 'ok'


@app.route("/device_remove", methods=['POST'])
def device_remove():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    with open('logs.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{name} Disconnected USB from IP: {request.remote_addr}\n')

    return 'ok'


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def device_list():
    keys = ['client', 'ip', 'status']
    data = []
    with open('logs.log', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            row = line.split()
            data.append(dict(zip(keys, [row[0], row[-1], row[1]])))


    return render_template_string(TABLE_TEMPLATE, data=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  socketio.run(app)
```

Client Side :

```
import requests
import subprocess, string, time
import os

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
name = os.uname()[1]

def on_device_add():
    requests.post(f'{url}/device_add?name={name}')
def on_device_remove():
    requests.post(f'{url}/device_remove?name={name}')

def detect_device(previous):
    total = subprocess.run('lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    time.sleep(3)

    # if condition if new device add
    if total > previous:
        on_device_add()
    # if no new device add or remove
    elif total == previous:
        detect_device(previous)
    # if device remove
    else:
        on_device_remove()
    # Infinite loop to keep client running.


while True:
    detect_device(subprocess.run(' lsblk | grep disk | wc -l', shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)
```

Comment: Adding a couple print statements in the connect and disconnect events it seems that socketio events are not firing properly. Not quite sure what's causing the problem though...

Answer (score 1):

After reading a bit of [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/) documentation I've managed to spot the problems in your code.

Not a problem per-se, but incrementing/decrementing an `int` counter is more than enough for this use case. Secondly, you don't have to pass that counter to the `render_template` call as you're basically passing the user count before the `conenct` event has had the opportunity to fire. You should emit a message (in this example with a `users` topic) that will inform your page that something has changed:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, logge=True)
clients = 0

@socketio.on("connect", namespace="/")
def connect():
    # global variable as it needs to be shared
    global clients
    clients += 1
    # emits a message with the user count anytime someone connects
    emit("users", {"user_count": clients}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on("disconnect", namespace="/")
def disconnect():
    global clients
    clients -= 1
    emit("users", {"user_count": clients}, broadcast=True)
```

Moreover, you didn't open a connection to the socket in your template, this allows you to listen to the messages emitted by your `socketio` decorators and update all connected clients. You will also need to write a bit of javascript to specify that the counter needs to be updated anytime a user connects/disconnects.

```html
<!-- Remember to import socketio library -->
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var namespace = '/';    
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
        // Update the counter when a new user connects
        socket.on('users', function(users) {
            userCount = document.getElementById('user_counter');
            userCount.innerHTML = users.user_count;
        });
});
</script>
<h1 id='user_counter'></h1>
<!-- the rest of your template -->
```

This being said, you **don't** need to pass the counter value in your `render_template` call.
Also, from `flask-socketio` [docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it seems to be good practice to start your app in the following way:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/t21KLjHN) a link to an edited version of your example.

Comment: hi thank you for this but there is a problem i run your code before connecting any client it say 1 client connect if i refresh it increment 2 , 3 and so on even no client is connect

Comment: That looks good to me except you **don't** need to pass the `threaded` argument when starting the app. Also, there's no need to import `typing.Counter`, why did you do that?

Comment: i changed everything but it keep showing 1 client connect 2 connect and so on even no 1 is connect. i update the post

Comment: That's correct, if you're viewing the page then your browser will be the connected client (hence **1** client connected)

Comment: no, i update my post when i run my client code then it should need to display client connected or 1 client i didn't run my client code but it keep showing 1 client

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the request. The original question was about updating the user count using websockets, which I've addressed already in my answer. Where does this client code come from? Also, that piece of code doesn't open a websocket connection so it won't affect the user count you see on the page. Connecting with your browser, on the other hand, will increase/decrease that count.